# Group UNIT selection with non empty value

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, union

Do you know some way for grouping a rows with the non empty values ?

For example:

```
ID  title  description address   
------------------------------------
1 | john | row1      |   EMPTY      
1 | john | EMPTY     |     2     
1 | john | EMPTY     |   EMPTY
```

RESULT

```
ID  title  description address
------------------------------------
1 | john | row1    |  2
```

The SELECT IS a UNION:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    title, 
    description, 
    address 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT a.id, a.title, b.value as description, "" as address
    FROM #__content as a 
    LEFT JOIN #__fieldsattach_values as b ON a.id = b.articleid 
    WHERE a.catid IN (15, 16) 
    AND b.fieldsid = 4 AND a.language = "ca-ES" AND a.state = "1" 
    GROUP BY a.id UNION ALL SELECT a.id, a.title, "" as description , b.value as address  
    FROM #__content as a LEFT JOIN #__fieldsattach_values as b ON a.id = b.articleid 
    WHERE a.catid IN (15, 16) AND b.fieldsid = 5 AND a.language = "ca-ES"
    AND a.state = "1" GROUP BY a.id
) AS z
```

Comment: You have made 3 different questions. I have already answered 2 of them. The 3rd one is up to you. If you want to make 3 different questions then you should create 3 different questions instead of editing the same question over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL you can use the GROUP_CONCAT function like this:

```
SELECT ID, Name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(Direction) AS Direction, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(Group) AS Group, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(Profile) AS Profile
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID, Name
```

If there is more than one non-empty value in a column, for each pair of ID and Name, the values will be concatenated with a comma as default.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the origin is

Select ID, Name, Direction, "" as Group, "" as Profile FROM name_table

UNION ALL

Select ID, Name, "" a Direction, group as Group, "" as Profile FROM name_table

UNION ALL

Select ID, Name, "" a Direction, "" as Group, profile as Profile FROM name_table

Thanks

Comment: You should have written that in your question. Anyway, wouldn't `SELECT ID, Name, Direction, Group, Profile FROM name_table` give you what you want, then?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do seems to be a bit dirty. By the way, I'm assuming `EMPTY` means `NULL`.

You can just group by and get the max value for the group. Bear in mind that, the same way as you show in your example, if you have more than one non-null value in the group you will only be keeping one (the maximum):

```
select id, name, max(direction), max(`group`), max(profile) from name_table
group by id
```

Note that `group` is a reserved word and that you could also group by `id` and `name` to make the query more *standard*.

**Edit:**

Based on your radical question edit, you could do the following to keep the same logic:

```
select id, name, max(direction), max(`group`), max(profile) from (
    Select ID, Name, Direction, "" as Group, "" Profile FROM name_table
    UNION ALL
    Select ID, Name, "" a Direction, group Group, "" Profile FROM name_table
    UNION ALL
    Select ID, Name, "" a Direction, "" Group, profile Profile FROM name_table
) s
group by id
```

Bear in mind `group` is a reserved word.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the origin is

Select ID, Name, Direction, "" as Group, "" as Profile FROM name_table

UNION ALL

Select ID, Name, "" a Direction, group as Group, "" as Profile FROM name_table

UNION ALL

Select ID, Name, "" a Direction, "" as Group, profile as Profile FROM name_table

Thanks

Comment: What are you talking about?